svn to git migration for older complex projects
I need to migrate a project from SVN to GIT. The SVN repo has the default structure tags, branch, and trunk, with a long commit history of more than 10 years. I use the command:
git svn clone -s <SVN_REPO_URL> <DEST_FOLDER_PATH>

but unable to replicate all the folders from SVN into the git folder. I find a few folders missing from the git migrated folder. I need to retain the log history, also when I rebase the git folder all the .hex, .bin, project files need to be resolved for conflicts, please suggest.
git svn clone -s <remote repo> <local repo>
git remote add origin url.git
git fetch origin
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main
git pull --rebase
git push

